# How to display "text is copied" to the user after the text has been copied?

Tags: react-native, native-base, touchableopacity

How to display "text is copied" to the user after the text has been copied?

```
const dataArray = [ { title: "Invoice Reference Number", content:QRCODE_SAMPLE.Irn } ];

<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}
    onPress={() => Clipboard.setString(QRCODE_SAMPLE.Irn)}>   
    <Accordion style={{paddingTop:10,paddingBottom:50,backgroundColor:'#E0DDDD'}}dataArray={dataArray} expanded={1}>
    </Accordion>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: You can use toast for doing so

Comment: @KaranMehta could you please elaborate?

Comment: When string has been stored in the clipboard, you should show toast to user to acknowledge them about the same

Comment: Still if you can't understand let me know i will show you how to do that

Comment: Yes, toast worked for me but how do I include both Clipboard.setString(QRCODE_SAMPLE.Irn)} and Toast.show in a single onPress?

Comment: You can write code for toast after adding string to the clipboard, Just add this after the another

Comment: @KaranMehta I got it, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
    import {ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';
```

Create this function :

```
    onCopyPressed(){

    Clipboard.setString(QRCODE_SAMPLE.Irn);
    ToastAndroid.show('A pikachu appeared nearby !', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    }
```

And call that function like this :

```
const dataArray = [ { title: "Invoice Reference Number", content:QRCODE_SAMPLE.Irn } ];
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}
        onPress={this.onCopyPressed.bind(this)}>   
        <Accordion style={{paddingTop:10,paddingBottom:50,backgroundColor:'#E0DDDD'}}dataArray={dataArray} expanded={1}>
        </Accordion>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never used the clipboard before but I assume your code is working, then:

```
const [clipboardString, setClipboardString] = useState('');

handleClipboardAction = (str) => () => {
    Clipboard.setString(str);
    setClipboardString(setClipboardString)
}

<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}
    onPress={handleClipboardAction(str)}>   
    <Accordion style={{paddingTop:10,paddingBottom:50,backgroundColor:'#E0DDDD'}}dataArray={dataArray} expanded={1}>
    </Accordion>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Then you can observe the state to see if there's anything copied and conditional render the "Text is copied" message:

```
{clipboardString.length > 0 && <Text>Text is copied</Text>}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way is using a package that mixes between them:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-clipboard-toast

> React Native Clipboard API with Animated toast message component
>
> Support both Android and iOS | Used react native Clipboard | Toast by
> calling api